# Unable to get result from https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?mine=1

Tags: yammer

I am trying get all groups of current user from Yammer, I have tried using

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?mine=1
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/current.json?include_group_memberships=true

I am using below code

```
yam.platform.request ( {
        url : "groups.json?mine=1",
        method : "GET",
        data : { },
        success : function ( group ) {
            alert('hi');
            alert(group);
            $mygroup = "";
            for ( $i = 0; $i < group.length; $i++ ) {
                $mygroup += '<img src="' + group [ $i ].mugshot_url + '">' + " " + group [ $i ].full_name + "," + "<br>";
            }
            $ ( "#current-groups" ).html ( $mygroup );
        },
        error : function ( group ) {
            alert ( "No Go" + group.results);
        }
    } );
```

I am always getting error.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing

```
data : { },
```

from my code, it started working

```
yam.platform.request ( {
    url : "groups.json?mine=1",
    method : "GET",
    data : { },
    success : function ( group ) {
        alert('hi');
        alert(group);
        $mygroup = "";
        for ( $i = 0; $i < group.length; $i++ ) {
            $mygroup += '<img src="' + group [ $i ].mugshot_url + '">' + " " + group [ $i ].full_name + "," + "<br>";
        }
        $ ( "#current-groups" ).html ( $mygroup );
    },
    error : function ( group ) {
        alert ( "No Go" + group.results);
    }
} );
```